# How to solve static:: call when its unavailable?

Tags: php, static, late-static-binding

I have a php 5.2 on my server (cant update) and it drops error on a `static::routin()` call. How to solve it? Anyway, is there a way, to detect if this type of call is available, so that an intelligent call-mechanism can be added?

Comment: 5.2 is oooold. And either you _can_ update, or you are on a shared host of a hoster you should leave, because he gives you unmaintained package versions.

Comment: You should not be using static methods to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late static bindings only work from PHP 5.3. To get the called class name in version 5.2 you have to use work arounds.

[From the manual](http://php.net/lsb):

```
As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.
```

[One work around exists here](http://il.php.net/lsb#100611).

Comment: I think the OP knows that -- he mentioned his PHP version and said he couldn't update.

Comment: @jprofitt actually his language doesnt sound as if the OP gets that, secondly I have offered him a work around!